How to add UI element to a Modifier
Is it possible to add a Button to a Modifier's UI? I need to add a Button to the Geometry node Modifier. I know how to make a button in a separate Panel but the Operation I want to perform is specific to the Nodetree, so placing the Button directly on the Modifier would be optimal.


I have no experiend with interfaces, but you might work this around by making your own panel that invokes a geometry node instead of using an actual geometry nodes panel.

I don't think this is possible, because all UI modification via Python has to be done on registering the script, which you can't do with live context-based data.

@Jakemoyo, I think you could register whatever panel you want and then check for correct conditions from the poll function - there is nothing preventing one from displaying a panel only if some specific modifier exists, the problem is that modifier UI is not written in Python and so you cannot access them.

Modifier UI is not accessible via Python API. It is not possible to add anything to a panel of a modifier in the Properties editor, Modifier tab using Python.
You can create various types of inputs for geometry nodes group:

Boolean value gives you a checkbox which is probably the closest thing to a button you can get in a Geometry Nodes modifier. You could also read the value of the checkbox from a script, although making that into any kind of an elegant solution might be a tricky task. You could use an app handler, but it would probably need to be depsgraph update handler and those run really often so you would have to make sure you check for something simple and run more code only if needed. You could look into Message Bus as well which would be better but I am not sure how(if at all) it works with modifier inputs.
It is also possible to add buttons to the Modifier tab in the Properties editor itself:
import bpy

def buttons(self, context):
    if (context.active_object):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.scale_y = 3.0
        row.operator("render.render")
            
def register():
    bpy.types.DATA_PT_modifiers.prepend(buttons)
    
def unregister():
    bpy.types.DATA_PT_modifiers.remove(buttons)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


